# XML syntax issue

Tags: xml, syntax, syntax-error

I have an error that's generated when I try to compile XML code of a URL. The code is this:

```
<href>http://ezproxy.uis.edu:2048/login?url=http://search.ebscohost.com/login.aspx?authtype=ip,uid&profile=ehost&defaultdb=27h</href>
```

The compiler tells me that I need a semi-colon after profile--but that would break the URL. Normally, this wouldn't be a problem (other URLs work fine), but there's quite a few URLs that are in this format. What can I do to fix it? Also, I'm fairly new to XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&` in XML must be encoded as `&amp;`. Otherwise, anything after it will be taken as a malformed attempt to use an entity.